# In Android Gradle, is there any way to use local snapshot dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, build-dependencies

My Android app is based on Gradle and it just takes ages to build every time. This is due to the number of modules I have. Even if there are no changes in submodules, it keeps rebuilding every sources.
I was wondering if there is any way to convert these modules to local snapshot dependencies as I'm not updating them often?
I'm pretty sure it's possible but I have a very basic experience with gradle and maven so I can't figure out a simple way to do that.

Basically right now I'm listing my dependencies like that:

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':Library:lib1')
    compile project(':Library:lib2')
    compile project(':Library:lib3')
}
```

and I'd like to use something like that:

```
repositories {
    local()
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.lib1:lib:SNAPSHOT-1.0')
    compile 'com.lib2:lib:SNAPSHOT-1.0')
    compile 'com.lib3:lib:SNAPSHOT-1.0')
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your sub projects are recompiled? It doesn't appear that way with the project I have, though it does merge the resources from the library projects. I guess that wouldn't change when you'll get the libs from somewhere else...

Comment: well i'm not sure if it's recompiling but it's doing stuff with modules. running via command line is much faster (I'll end up using my shell script as a workaround for running quicker). But even then it's doing stuff with the modules (mergeReleaseAssets, mergeReleaseResources, processReleaseManifest etc...) while it's not doing anything with the remote compiled dependencies.

Comment: What is the output of Gradle? Does it say "UP-TO-DATE" when building lib1? If it does, it skips building libs. Partial builds is one of main Gradle features.

Answer (score 0):

To use local snapshots use the [maven-publish](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin. If you use SNAPSHOT in the version (e.g. 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT) you will publish snapshots to your local repository. For the build.gradle for lib1 you should do something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

project.version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

and run the :publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal target.

In you gradle build file for projects using the library use:

```
repositories {
    local()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.lib1', name: 'lib', version: 'SNAPSHOT-0.0.1', changing: true
}
```

The 'changing' attribute indicates that not a cached version is used (normally updated once every 24hrs) but always checks for the latest.